# How can I convert a slice into a slice of fixed length and back

Tags: go, slice

How can I convert []int into [3]int?

non of those work:

```
    vec := []int{1, 2, 3}
    
    t1 := [3]int(vec)
    t2 := [3]int(vec[:])
    //cannot convert vec (variable of type []int) to [3]int
    
    t3 := [3]int{}
    copy(t3, vec)
    //invalid argument: copy expects slice arguments; found t3 (variable of type [3]int) and vec 
    //(value of type []int)
```

Comment: Try `copy(t3[:],vec)`

Comment: Terminology issue that might be getting in your way: `[3]int` isn't a slice type, it's an array type. That's why `copy` doesn't accept it. @BurakSerdar's suggestion gives you a slice that spans the whole array.

Comment: To initialize an array value from a slice in current versions of Go, use `copy` as suggested  by @BurakSerdar.  The following one-liner will be possible in Go 1.17: `t3 := *(*[3]int)(vec)`

Comment: "slice of fixed length" isn't a thing. I think you mean "array"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [Go playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/f41woqC8DHN) that might make it more clear what's going on with `copy(t3[:],vec)`.

Go Playground example code :

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    slice := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
    var array [3]int
    arrayAsSlice := array[:]      // arrayAsSlice storage IS array; they are aliased.
    copy(arrayAsSlice, slice[:3]) // copy into arrayAsSlice modifies array, too.
    arrayAsSlice[0] = -1          // slice and array are STILL aliased

    arrayAsSlice = append(arrayAsSlice, 99) // slice cannot grow in the memory it has, therefore, it is reallocated.
    arrayAsSlice[0] = 0                     // Now slice and array are NOT aliased, so this does not modify the array

    fmt.Printf("Hello, playground, %+v", array)
}
```